# How to decide `end of transmission` symbol for arithmetic coding?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

In Mackay's Information Theory book (p. 111), he's said that

> Let the source alphabet be $\mathcal{A}_X = \{a_1, . . . , a_I\}$, and
>   let the $I$th symbol $a_I$ have the special meaning ‘end of transmission’.

which seems quite arbitrary to me. More importantly, there might involve a risk of corrupting decoding process, since $a_I$ cannot be translated (it's replaced with `end of transmission` symbol).

To specify my idea, suppose, we have $\mathcal{A}_x=\{a,b,c\}$ and probabilities $p (a) = 0 . 25 , p (b) = 0 . 25 , p (c) = 0 . 5$. If we want to encode a string $abc$, how to decide the `end of transmission` symbol and its probability? Are we randomly set some probability $p(d)$ as `end of transimisson` and  then rescale $p(a), p(b), p(c)$ according to that probability?

**Edited**

To be clear, the scope of question is **artihmatric** coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will choose a probability for EOT dependant on how long your message typically is, as though it were part of every message in your corpus. Thus in your probability selecting corpus "abc" is really "abc." And "qrxjundieko" is really "qrxjundieko." And so forth.

Note that my use of a period there implies that there are no other periods in the entire corpus. Really you use a special symbol that's guaranteed not to be there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the algorithm of Huffman coding is different from arithmetic coding, and the scope of this question is arithmetic coding.

Comment: Aha, one moment, the answer is slightly different there.

Comment: You've mentioned that prob of EOT depends on the length of message, could you clarify it a little bit of how to set this prob of EOT? Does that mean differnt choice of $p(EOT)$ would result to different codewords?

Comment: It can, yes. Choosing the probability correctly means that a random real number gives a message that has a character density *and length* similar to a typical message in the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

> More importantly, there might involve a risk of corrupting decoding process, since $a_I$ cannot be translated

No, the symbol $a_I$ means exclusively EOT (end of trasmission). If you want to trasmit three symbols $\mathcal{A}_x=\{a,b,c\}$ (which might appear anywhere in the stream) then you need to augment that with the extra EOT symbol.

Bear in mind that the EOT symbol is only one way, another possibility is to prepend the coded sequence with the sequence length.

Comment: Would EOT and length prepend methods generate the same result?

Comment: @Logan Surely not, but they will both be asymptotically negligible